# How do you return CGI headers from php?

Tags: php, apache, cgi

How does php return CGI headers?

I've been writing CGI 'scripts' in C++, and this is straightforward: I just manually output a `Content-type` and a `Status` line. However, I need to use phpmailer, so I also have some php code. The problem is that my simple php code just works, even though I'm not explicitly returning any headers. I've got to the point where I now have to return a failure status code to the client, and I can't see how I'm meant to do this. Any ideas? Is Apache doing this automatically for me and, if so, how do I persuade it to return a 400 status?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), send a header that starts with "HTTP/".

```
header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
```

Answer (score 0):

Php has this function for things like you need:

[Php header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Example:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the header function to add custom headers. Please refer to the header function documentation.

[PHP Header](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)